# Is it possible to post FBML (a way to use HTML-like content) data through Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml, facebook-iframe

Any way to join FBML and Graph API to post HTML to a FB page?
FB Iframe's based solutions are welcome too.

---

**EDIT 24 hrs after**: After play with the [Page Tab](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) functionality I have found that it is the best way to embed custom content (HTML/CSS/javascript) inside FB pages.

Basically are iframes. In the `Page tab` settings you must enter the URL to embed. That's all! You can use [Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) to get the `id`'s page and something called `app_data`. With that you can dynamically manage your embedded content!!!

Thanks to DMCS to guide me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, while the FBML is being deprecated, there is another way to accomplish posting something to a page.

You can see an example here of what is called a page tab application.  It is an app specifically designed to be used on a Facebook page.  It becomes a tab (can even be set to the default of what a visitor sees).

Here's an example: http://www.facebook.com/GoDaddy?sk=app_233280480043288

You can see that the content is HTML and you have full control over that HTML since it lives on your server.  This also demonstrates how a fan-gate operates.

Comment: Where is explained how was embedded that picture using Graph API? THX.-

Comment: That picture as well as the other HTML is served up via an iFrame.  You specify the iFrame url in your app settings. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: +1 I see something very interesting in [Integrating with Facebook APIs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating) at the bottom of the page you show about `app_data`!. I'll check it deeper and return here to accept your answer if all goes OK. THX!!

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

> **We are deprecating FBML. On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be supported on Platform.** June 1, 2012: FBML apps will no longer work. All FBML endpoints are removed. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML.

Comment: +1 I know it. But we have time until June to wait for new solutions. So in the meantime FBML is acceptable. Any tip about using Graph API with FBML? THX.-

Comment: There won't be any "new solutions" in June. They've already replaced it with iframe tabs.

Comment: With `new solutions` I meant an easy way to post HTML into FB via API. Any tip about using Graph API with FBML or iframes? That is my question.

Comment: Post into FB? Post what? Wall posts? In most situations I'd imagine Facebook doesn't *want* you posting HTML.

Comment: FBML is a markup language that `looks as HTML`, right?. iframes allow embed HTML into FB, right? that is what I mean. You are no responding to my question. This response should have been a comment.

Comment: Your statements are unclear, hence my attempts to clarify. iframes applications replace FBML for Facebook Tabs and Canvas applications. Using iframe apps, server-side programming and the Graph API you can do essentially everything you could do with FBML.

Comment: So then please put an answer to my question! I asked for fbml or iframe. The only thing that I want is to use them via an API!

Comment: You're not giving any indication of **what** you want to post via API. You don't actually **need** any APIs to put together a basic iframe app for Facebook - they're for pulling data out of Facebook and for doing things like generating wall posts, photos, etc. You just create a Facebook app and point it at your URL. You need to go read the docs.

Comment: Forget it man. DMCS was in the right way from the beginning. Thanks.-

Comment: I'm sorry your question was unclear. Based on your comments here, I believe the question really should've read "How do I create a Facebook iframe application?".

Comment: In the last hour I have received downvotes in several previous questions and answers and you have decreased your reputation in a couple of points too, so it is clear that was you. What a shame... Please stop it!